# Modeling uncertainty from known physics

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to request some help from the  data science community.

My task with machine learning is do achieve the following in `pyTorch`:

I have an equation given by:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} t}=4a−2s+\lambda(s)
$$

Where $a$ is an input constant and $\lambda$ is a non-linear term that depends on $s$.

I know that the true solution for $\lambda\left(s\right)$ is $\sin \left( s\right) \cos\left(s\right)$

I have generated data from [0, 5]s with the true solution and with the equation excluding the non-linear term for a range of initial conditions and a range of $a$'s.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def foo_true(t, s, a):
    ds_dt = 4*a -2*s + np.sin(s)*np.cos(s)
    return ds_dt

def foo(t, s, a):
    ds_dt = 4*a -2*s
    return ds_dt


# Settings:
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000) 

a_s = np.arange(1, 10)
s0_s = np.arange(1, 10)

# Store the data
df_true = pd.DataFrame({'time': t})
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': t})

# Generate the data
for a in a_s:
    for s0 in s0_s:
        sol_true = solve_ivp(foo_true, (t[0], t[-1]), (s0,), t_eval=t, args=(a,))
        df_true[f'{a}_{s0}'] = sol_true.y.T
        
for a in a_s:
    for s0 in s0_s:
        sol = solve_ivp(foo, (t[0], t[-1]), (s0,), t_eval=t, args=(a,))    
        df[f'{a}_{s0}'] = sol.y.T
```

In the above code, `df_true` is a data frame containing the true dynamics of the system and `df` the dynamics with a discrepancy.

The figure bellow shows the an example in discrepancy of the data:

[image]

Given that I know part of the physics, how can I model $\lambda$?

Does anyone know of a paper/repo with a conceptually similar example that I can a look into?

Best regards

Comment: You need to explain what you mean be generating data from this differential equation, what the actual data looks like, and if there is any statistical model involved

Comment: In the post, you have code that will solve the ODE with ground truth dynamic `df_true` and with some discrepancy `df` for a range of initial conditions and variations of $a$. I would like to use ML to infer a correction term between the data in `df` and `df_true`.

Comment: People shouldn't have to decipher your code in order to understand the question. You should explain more clearly what is the input data and what you are trying to estimate from it.

Comment: I will try to improve the question. Thanks for the remark

Comment: you may be interested in the Kennedy O'Hagan framework: https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9868.00294

Comment: Your differential equation has an exact solution. Is that what you are looking for? Is this some sort of exercise from a course? Could you explain where this problem comes from.

Comment: What do you mean with 'how can I model $\lambda$'? You know it already $\lambda(s) = \sin(s)\cos(s) = 0.5 \sin(2s)$. In what sense is there something to model?

Comment: *"Modeling uncertainty from known physics"* What uncertainty?

Comment: Hello @SextusEmpiricus. This is a toy-example I gave myself to try to understand how you can enhance a model with data, given limited knowledge on the physics of the problem. In this problem (there is no noisy data), the system is composed by something you know `ds_dt = 4*a -2*s` + something you don't know. However, you have the actual data that describe the dynamics of the system. So the concept is how can you use the physics you know + data to create an enhanced version of the original model capable of describing the dynamics of the system.

Comment: @nopnop So your question is not about uncertainty, in the sense of random behaviour, but about expressing an unknown term? $$\lambda(t) = 2s-4a-ds/dt$$ If there is no noise, why not simply plot an approximation of $\lambda(t)$ by replacing $ds/dt \approx \Delta s/ \Delta t$?

Comment: `but about expressing an unknown term`. That is exactly it! Is the term misleading?  Should I change the title? I want to use machine learning and the available data to model what is missing from my known physics.

Comment: It may possibly better if you use a real example instead of a toy example. It is unclear what 'machine learning' is gonna add when you already have the unknown term by simply rewriting the equation where the unknown term is expressed in terms of the known terms.

Comment: I might not be explaining this properly, but in this problem you have only the data with the true dynamics and only know part of the physics (measurements in time). Now you need a model that complements the known physics with the data. The fact that the non-linear term is known is irreverent (it was just used to have data). Now I want to model what I am missing from the known physics with the data I have

Comment: Rewrite the equation such that the unknown term is on one side of the equation. Plot it, now you have your unknown term extracted from the data and you can model it however you like.

Comment: Can you provide an answer with your strategy using a ML technique (?`ANN` `resnet` `neuralODE` `PINN` `deepONet`? unfortunately I not familiar with the appropriate technique to use in this problem.

Comment: @nopnop there is no ML needed for your toy problem. Possibly you may have left something out that makes ML important for your real problem.

Comment: The important part is not knowing the form of $\lambda(s)$. Imagine that instead of $\sin(s) \cos(s)$ it  has the form $\nabla \cdot \nabla s$. Will machine leaning make more sense?

Comment: So the ML task is to turn the known data $\lambda(s)$ into some expression? You have some values $\lambda(s) = 1,2,1,2,1,2$ and the algorithm should tell you what function it is. But there are infinite possibilities here (e.g. it can be a sine wave, but also polynomial). You have to add some restrictions for such problem to have a solution.

Comment: You don't have data on $\lambda(s)$ you have data on $s(t)$. You can generate it by doing the what you suggested and moving everything to lhs to get $lhs = \lambda(s)$. The algorithm does not need to tell you the actual form of $\lambda(s)$. It should end up with $\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} t}=4a−2s + NeuralNetwork(s)$ that approaches the correct results

Comment: What sort of approach is the neural network supposed to give? Why are you using a model? Models are a stylized simplified version of reality; what sort of simplification are you looking for? Your question boils down to, I have data $\lambda(s)$ how do I model this with ML? Without context this can not be answered.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the needed context? My model is missing something to fit my observations. I want to model what is missing with an appropriate machine learning technique.

Comment: The answer to a question 'how do I model' requires an explanation of the *goal* why one needs a model in the first place. Why do you need a model if you have the real data without any noise? What is the point of modelling it? With answers to such questions you can follow it up with what *properties* should the model have. [Think about the saying "all models are wrong, but some are useful", you can not sensibly just start modelling with any tool without knowing what 'useful' is. You need context.]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146284/discussion-on-question-by-nop-nop-modeling-uncertainty-from-known-physics); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $s(t)$ then you can express the unknown term $\gamma(t) = \lambda(t) + 4a$ as

$$\gamma(t) = 2s(t) + \frac{\text{d}s(t)}{\text{d}t}  \approx 2s(t) +  \frac{\Delta s(t)}{\Delta t} $$

The approximation works if there is little noise and if the sampling frequency is high (not too much change of the slope within a time period $\Delta t$).

With your example the true model is:

$$s(t) = 2a + (y_0 + 0.125 - 2a) \exp(-2t) + 0.125 \sin(2t) - 0.125  \cos(2t)$$

And an example with $a = 3$ and $y_0 = 3$ looks like

[image: example]

Then if we plot $2s(t) +  \frac{\Delta s(t)}{\Delta t}$ we get something that resembles your original sine wave

[image: example]

If you would know the term $a$ then you can subtract it to get $\lambda(t) = \gamma(t) - 4a$. Otherwise you can not know $\gamma(t)$ because you can always subtract or add a constant value to it and you do not know which is the case without any additional information.

---

How you want to estimate/model that final result is a matter that depends on your use case. Note the saying ["all models are wrong, but some are useful"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong). You can not sensibly just start modelling with an arbitrary tool without knowing what 'useful' is.

You need context. A question 'how do I model' requires an explanation of the goal why one needs a model in the first place. Why do you need a model if you have the real data without any noise? What is the point of modelling it? With answers to such questions you can follow it up with describing what properties the model should have.

---

Below is some R code to generate the above two figures. You can also make it work with noise, but then the parameters for the filter that is used to compute the derivative need to be changed.

Alternatively, if you know the functional form of $\lambda(t)$ or a family that it belongs to, then you can potentially solve the differential equation and describe $\lambda(t)$ in terms of $s(t)$ without the need for differentiation.

Also, instead of differentiation, one may also use integration (which is less sensitive to noise), but the plotted result $\int_0^t \gamma(x) dx$ is not always easy to interpret. An example of using integration is in the use of fitting a function that is a sum of exponential terms $\sum a_i exp(-b_i t)$ to find a starting condition for other algorithms.

```
### generate data
dt = 5/1000
t = seq(0, 5, dt)
a = 3
y0 = 3
s = 2*a + (y0 + 0.125 - 2*a) * exp(-2*t) + 0.125 * sin(2*t) - 0.125 * cos(2*t)

### plot data
plot(t,s, type = "l",
     main = expression(s(t) == 2*a + (y[0] + 0.125 - 2*a) * exp(-2*t) + 0.125 * sin(2*t) - 0.125 * cos(2*t)),
     cex.main = 0.8)

### compute lambda
### savgol is a Savitzky Golay filter that we use to compute a derivative
gamma = 2*s + pracma::savgol(s, fl = 3, forder = 1, dorder = 1)/dt

### plotting
range = 2:(length(t)-1) ### trim first and last case where derivative is not computed
plot(t[range], gamma[range], type = "l", ylim = c(11,13),
     main = expression(gamma(t) == 2*s(t) + over(Delta * s(t), Delta * t)),
cex.main = 0.8, ylab = "gamma", xlab = "t")
```